# ImageMagick Identify Fails

Tags: imagemagick

The `identify` binary is giving me an error. Has anyone seen this before? Google isn't being very helpful.

```
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
Loading plugin imagemagick
imagemagick plugin successfully instantiated
Check the version of the imagemagick plugin
The version of the imagemagick plugin is ok
getcwd()
chdir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
realpath(/nfs)
is_dir(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/gm)
realpath(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/identify)
realpath(/nfs)
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/identify)
getParameter exec.beNice for core plugin
Executing: ( "/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/data/bin/identify" 
"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif"
)
2>"/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgVVafbw"
getParameter exec.expectedStatus for core plugin
file_exists(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgVVafbw)
filesize(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgVVafbw)
unlink(/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/g2data/tmp/g2dbgVVafbw)
Regular Output:
/nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144213/domains/thisnthatcompany.com/html/gallery/modules/imagemagick/data/test.gif
GIF 50x50 50x50+0+0 8-bit sRGB 8c 232B 0.000u 0:00.000
Error Output:
Status: 0 (expected 0)
```

Comment: Looks just fine to me, identify starts and identifies the image. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry your right. Heres a screen shot. http://cl.ly/L9fH

Comment: A screenshot of what? Which testing tool is this, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test tool seems to expect no output from identify. It's sole purpose is to provide output (identification of the image). THis is a fault in the test tool, not in identify.